# pythonのフィールドエラー

Tags: python, django

python、djangoの初心者で、参考書を参考し、SNSアプリを写経しているのですが

> Cannot resolve keyword 'groups' into field.

というエラーに行き詰っています。
anaconda。windows10を使用しています。

だれか心優しい方助けていただけないでしょうか。
**エラーコード**

```
Environment:


Request Method: GET
Request URL: http://127.0.0.1:8000/sns/

Django Version: 2.2.5
Python Version: 3.7.4
Installed Applications:
['django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'sns']
Installed Middleware:
['django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware']



Traceback:

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\exception.py" in inner
  34.             response = get_response(request)

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  115.                 response = self.process_exception_by_middleware(e, request)

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py" in _get_response
  113.                 response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  21.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\tumek\Desktop\django_app\sns\views.py" in index
  65.         messages = get_your_group_message(request.user,glist,None)

File "C:\Users\tumek\Desktop\django_app\sns\views.py" in get_your_group_message
  299.             |Q(groups__in=me_groups))[:100]

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\manager.py" in manager_method
  82.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in filter
  892.         return self._filter_or_exclude(False, *args, **kwargs)

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\query.py" in _filter_or_exclude
  910.             clone.query.add_q(Q(*args, **kwargs))

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in add_q
  1290.         clause, _ = self._add_q(q_object, self.used_aliases)

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1312.                     current_negated, allow_joins, split_subq, simple_col)

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in _add_q
  1318.                     split_subq=split_subq, simple_col=simple_col,

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in build_filter
  1190.         lookups, parts, reffed_expression = self.solve_lookup_type(arg)

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in solve_lookup_type
  1049.         _, field, _, lookup_parts = self.names_to_path(lookup_splitted, self.get_meta())

File "C:\Users\tumek\Anaconda3\envs\myspace\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py" in names_to_path
  1420.                                      "Choices are: %s" % (name, ", ".join(available)))

Exception Type: FieldError at /sns/
Exception Value: Cannot resolve keyword 'groups' into field. Choices are: content, good, good_count, group, group_id, id, owner, owner_id, pub_date, share_count, share_id
```

**ソースコード**

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms
from.models import Message,Group,Friend,Good
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

#Messageフォーム

class Messageform(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Message
        fields = ['owner','group','content']

#Groupフォーム

class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Group
        fields = ['owner','title']

#Friendフォーム

class FriendForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Friend
        fields = ['owner','user','group']

#Goodのフォーム

class GoodForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Good
        fields = ['owner','message']

#検索フォーム

class SearchForm(forms.Form):
    search = forms.CharField(max_length=100)


#Groupチェックボックスフォーム

class GroupCheckForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupCheckForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        public = User.objects.filter(username='public').first()
        self.fields['groups'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=[(item.title,item.title)for item in \
                Group.objects.filter(owner__in=[user,public])],
            widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple(),
        )
# Groupの選択メニューフォーム

class GroupSelectForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(GroupSelectForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['groups'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=[('-','-')]+[(item.title,item.title) \
                for item in Group.objects.filter(owner=user)],
        )


#Friendのチェックボックスフォーム

class FriendsForm(forms.Form):
    def __init__(self, user, friends=[], vals=[], *args, **kwargs):
        super(FriendsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['friends'] = forms.MultipleChoiceField(
            choices=[(item.user,item.user)for item in friends],
            widget=forms.CheckBoxSelectMultiple(),
            initial=vals
        )

#Group 作成フォーム

class CreateGroupForm(forms.Form):
    group_name = forms.CharField(max_length=50)

#投稿フォーム

class PostForm(forms.Form):
    content = forms.CharField(max_length=500, \
            widget = forms.Textarea)
    def __init__(self, user, *args, **kwargs):
        super(PostForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        public = User.objects.filter(username='public').first()
        self.fields['groups'] = forms.ChoiceField(
            choices=[('-','-')]+[(item.title,item.title) \
                     for item in Group.objects. \
                     filter(owner__in=[user,public])],
        )
```

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.contrib import messages

from.models import Message,Friend,Group,Good
from.forms import GroupCheckForm,GroupSelectForm, \
    SearchForm,FriendsForm,CreateGroupForm,PostForm

from django.db.models import Q
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

#indexのview関数

@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')
def index(request):
    #publicのuserを取得
    (public_user, public_group)=get_public()

    #PoST送信時の処理
    if request.method == 'POST':


        #Groupsのチェックを更新した時の処理
        if request.POST['mode'] == '__check_form__':
            #フォームの用意
            searchform = SearchForm()
            checkform = GroupCheckForm(request.user,request.POST)
            #チェックされたGroup名をリストにまとめる
            glist = []
            for item in request.POST.getlist('groups'):
                glist.append(item)
                #Messageの取得
            messages = get_your_group_message(request.user, \
                    glist, None)
        #Groupsメニューを変更したときの処理
        if request.POST['mode'] == '__search_form__':
            # フォームの用意
            searchform = SearchForm(request.POST)
            checkform = GroupCheckForm(request.user)
            #Groupのリストを取得
            gps = Group.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
            glist = [public_group]
            for item in gps:
                glist.append(item)
            #メッセージを取得
            message = get_your_group_message(request.user, glist, \
                    request.POST['search'])
    #GETアクセス時の処理
    else:
        #フォームの用意
        searchform = SearchForm()
        checkform = GroupCheckForm(request.user)
        #Groupのリストを取得
        gps =Group.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        glist = [public_group]
        for item in gps:
            glist.append(item)
        #メッセージの取得
        messages = get_your_group_message(request.user,glist,None)
    #共通処理
    params = {
            'login_user':request.user,
            'contents':messages,
            'check_form':checkform,
            'search_form':searchform,
        }
    return render(request,'sns/index.html',params)

@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')
def groups(request):
    #自分が登録したFriendを取得
    friends = Friend.objects.filter(owner=request.user)

    #POST送信時の処理
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Groupメニュー選択肢の処理
        if request.POST['mode'] == '__groups_form__':
            #選択したGroup名を取得
            sel_group = request.POST['groups']
            #Groupを取得
            gp = Group.objests.filter(owner=request.user) \
                .filter(title=sel_group).first()
            #Groupに含まれるFriendsを取得
            fds = Friend.objects.filter(owner=request.user) \
                .filter(group=gp)
            #FriendのUserをリストにまとめる
            vlist =[]
            for item in fds:
                vlist.append(item.user.username)
            #フォームの用意
            groupsform = GroupSelectForm(request.user,request.POST)
            friendsform = FriendsForm(request.user, \
                    friends=friends, vals=vlist)

        # Friendsのチェック更新時の処理
        if request.POST['mode'] == '__friends_form__':
            #選択したGroupの取得
            sel_group = request.POST['group']
            group_obj = Group.objects.filter(title=sel_group).first()
            #チェックしたFriendsを取得
            sel_fds = request.POST.getlist('friends')
            #FriendsのUserを取得
            sel_users = User.objects.filter(username__in=sel_fds)
            #Userのリストに含まれるユーザーが登録したFriendsを取得
            fds = Friends.objects.filter(owner.request.user) \
                .filter(user__in=sel_users)
            #すべてのFriendsにgroupを設定し保存する
            vlist = []
            for item in fds:
                item.group = group_obj
                item.save()
                vlist.append(item.user.username)
            #メッセージを設定
            messages.success(request,'チェックしたFriendを'+ \
                    sel_group+'に登録しました。')
            #フォームの用意
            groupsform = GroupSelectForm(request.user, \
                    {'groups':sel_group})
            friendsform = FriendsForm(request.user, \
                friends=friends, vals=vlist)

    #GETアクセス時の処理
    else:
        #フォームの用意
        groupsform = GroupSelectForm(request.user)
        friendsform = FriendsForm(request.user,friends=friends, \
                vals=[])
        sel_group = '-'

    #共通処理
    createform = CreateGroupForm()
    params= {
            'login_user':request.user,
            'groups_form':groupsform,
            'friends_form':friendsform,
            'create_form':createform,
            'group':sel_group,
        }
    return render(request, 'sns/groups.html',params)

#Friendの追加処理
@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')
def add(request):
    #追加するUserを取得
    add_name = request.GET['name']
    add_user = User.objects.filter(username=add_name).first()
    #Userが本人だった場合の処理
    if add_user == request.user:
        messages.info(request,"自分自身をFriendに追加することは出来ません")
        return redirect(to='/sns')

    # ここからFriendの登録処理
    frd = Friend()
    frd.owner = request.user
    frd.user = add_user
    frd.group = public_group
    frd.save()

    #　メッセージを設定

    message.success(request, add_user.username +'を追加しました \
        group ページに移動して、追加したfriendをメンバーに設定して下さい')
    return redirect(to='/sns')

#グループの作成処理
@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')
def creategroup(request):
    #gorupを作り、userとtitleを設定して保存する
    gp =Group()
    gp.owner = request.user
    gp.title = request.POST['group_name']
    gp.save()
    messages.info(requset,'新しいグループを作成しました')
    return redirect(to='/sns/groups')

#メッセージのポスト処理
@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')
def post(requset):
    #POST送信の処理
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #送信内容の取得
        gr_name= request.POST['groups']
        content = request.POST['content']
        # groupの取得
        group = Group.objects.filter(owner=request.user) \
                .filter(title=gr_name).first()
        if group == None:
            (pub_user, group) = get_public()
        #messageを作成し設定を保存
        msg = Message()
        msg.owner = request.user
        msg.group = group
        msg.content = content
        msg.save()
        #メッセージの設定
        messages.success(request,'新しいメッセージを送信しました')
        return redirect(to='/sns')
    #GETアクセス時の処理
    else:
        form = PostForm(request.user)

    #共通処理
    params = {
            'login_user':request.user,
            'form':form,
            }
    return render(request,'sns/post.html',params)

#投稿をシェアする
@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')
def share(request,share_id):
    #shareするmessageの取得
    share = Message.objects.get(id=share_id)

    #POST送信時の処理
    if request.method =='POST':
        #送信内容を取得
        gr_name =request.POST['groups']
        content = request.POST['content']
        #groupの取得
        group = Group.objects.filter(owner=request.user) \
                .filter(title=gr_name).first()
        if group == None:
            (pub_user, group) = get_public()
        #メッセージを作成し、設定をして保存
        msg= Message()
        msg.owner = request.user
        msg.group = group
        msg.content = content
        msg.share_id = share.id
        msg.save()
        share_msg = msg.get_share()
        share_msg.share_count +=1
        share_msg.save()
        #メッセ-ジを設定
        messages.success(request,'メッセージをシェアしました。')
        return redirect(to='/sns')
    #共通処理
    form = PostForm(request.user)
    params = {
            'login_user':request.user,
            'form':form,
            'share':share,
            }
    return render(request, 'sns/share.html',params)

#goodボタンの処理
@login_required(login_url='/admin/login/')
def good(request, good_id):
    #goodするmessageを取得
    good_msg =Message.objects.get(id=good_id)
    #自分がメッセージにGOODした数を調べる
    is_good = Good.objects.filter(owner=request.user) \
        .filter(message=good_msg).count()
    #ゼロより大きければすでにgood済み
    if is_good > 0:
        messages.succces(request,'すでにメッセージにgoodしています')
        return redirect(to='sns/')
    #messaseのgood_countを１増やす
    good_msg.save()
    #Goodを作成し、設定を保存
    good = Good()
    good.owner = request.user
    good.message = good_msg
    good.save()
    #メッセージの設定
    messages.success(request,'メッセージにGoodしました')
    return redirect(to='sns/')

#これ以降はview関数ではなく普通の関数==================================
#指定されたグループおよび検索文字によるmessageの取得
def get_your_group_message(owner, glist, find):
        #publicの取得
    (public_user,public_group) = get_public()
    #チェックされたgroupの取得
    groups = Group.objects.filter(Q(owner=owner)\
        |Q(owner=public_user)).filter(title__in=glist)
    #groupに含まれるfriendの取得
    me_friends = Friend.objects.filter(group__in=groups)
    #Friendのuserをリストにまとめる
    me_users= []
    for f in me_friends:
        me_users.append(f.user)   
    his_groups = Group.objects.filter(owner__in =me_users)
    his_friends = Friend.objects.filter(user=owner) \
            .filter(group__in=his_groups)
    me_groups = []
    for hf in his_friends:
        me_groups.append(hf.group)
    # groupがgrouｐｓに含まれるか、me_groupsに含まれるmessageの取得
    if find == None:
        messages = Message.objects.filter(Q(group__in=groups) \
            |Q(groups__in=me_groups))[:100]
    else:
        messages = Message.objects.filter(Q(group__in=groups) \
            |Q(groups__in=me_groups)).filter(content__contains=find)[:100]
    return messages 
def get_public():
    public_user = User.objects.filter(username='public').first()
    public_group = Group.objects.filter \
            (owner=public_user).first()
    return (public_user, public_group)
```

Answer (score 1):

エラーメッセージとトレースバックを読む限り、Messageモデルにgroupsフィールドが無いにもかかわらずルックアップを行っているのが原因のようです。タイプミスでしょうか？

Answer (score 1):

forms.pyで#Messageフォームと#Friendフォームで
groupになっているのに、途中からgroupsになってます

Answer (score 1):

（既存の2つの回答を補足する形になりますが）エラーメッセージにそのように書いてあります。

> `Cannot resolve keyword 'groups' into field. Choices are: content, good, good_count, group, group_id, id, owner, owner_id, pub_date, share_count, share_id`
>
> `groups` というキーワードを解決できません。選べるのは: `content, good, good_count, group, group_id, id, owner, owner_id, pub_date, share_count, share_id` のいずれかです。

とある通りで、この中にある `group` の記入ミスであると気付くことができます。

また、どこを直すかもスタックトレースに記載してあるとおりで、

> File "C:\Users\tumek\Desktop\django_app\sns\views.py" in get_your_group_message
> 299.             |Q(groups__in=me_groups))[:100]

views.pyの299行目を修正すれば良いことが分かります。